# tableとthやtdの間にformがある場合、confirmダイアログが出なくなってしまいます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, html5

Ruby on Railsで開発をしております。

```
button_to '削除', xxxx_path(xxx.id), method: :delete, confirm: '本当に削除しますか？'

#=> <input class="button" data-confirm="本当に削除しますか？" name="commit" type="submit" value="削除" />
```

↑のような削除ボタンを作成しており、削除自体は成功するものの、confirmダイアログが成功する場合と成功しない場合がありました。

なぜかと思い、調べている中で、このような記事を見つけました。
http://qiita.com/yuji0222/items/80fd7a25486f8bb85752

どうもtableとthやtdの間にformがある場合、confirmダイアログが出ないみたいです。

そのことがわかったものの、対策案が見つからなかったため、現状はconfirmダイアログを出すのを断念しております。

もし、tableの中で、confirmダイアログを表示できる方法があるようでしたらアドバイスを頂きたく思います。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: <table>直下に<form>を置いてはいけないのです。が、そう書いてもブラウザは正しく処理できますので、Ruby on Rails のバグなのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

全体を `FORM` で囲むか、`TD`, `TH` の中に `FORM` を入れる必要があります。それが出来ない場合には、HTMLの構造を見直す必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

HTMLの要素は直下の子要素に入れられる要素が限定されているものもあります。
これはダメですが、

```
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

これならOKです

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```